# How to find my Ambari server URL

Tags: hadoop

How do I find my Ambari server hostname?

https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.1/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-chap3-1.html

Comment: @Rinzwind Perhaps that should be an answer with the relevant parts pulled out and explained here?

Comment: https://teraone.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/how-to-find-ambari-server-host-port-on-hortonworks-installation/

Answer (score 1):

The `main.install.hostname` in the documentation was a placeholder referring to the machine's hostname where `ambari` is installed and in my case it is `localhost`

I had to point my browser to http://localhost:8080 and it worked